# Unregistering a service in application that uses NSD

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifip2p

I'm making an app that uses Network Service Discovery, let's call it a "Wi-fi Chat". And at some point I want to unregister a service created earlier in order to avoid creation of countless copies of it. But the problem is, when I cal;

```
mNsdManager.unregisterService(mRegistrationListener);
```

I get "listener is not registered" error. To make sure that I have STILL THE SAME object of that listener I even initialized it in a class that extends Application class and still I get this error. So, the question is: **how to unregister a service properly?** Thank you in advance.

Also, I looked through "NsdChat" sample application, and it crashes at the same point with the same error!

Comment: Where you register the listener

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kinda found a solution. Much thanks to [this Wizard](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/73f1ba806fe5fa0dad2334b168deefaf6d8ca5c3/samples/training/NsdChat/src/com/example/android/nsdchat/NsdHelper.java) who fixed NsdChat Google example.

The solution is: in tearDown() method, inside which we call unregisterService(RegistrationListener listener) we should do this

```
public void tearDown() {
        if (mRegistrationListener != null) {
            try {
                mNsdManager.unregisterService(mRegistrationListener);
            } finally {
            }
            mRegistrationListener = null;
        }
    }
```

Though I still have no clue how actually this works, so if you have any thoughts regarding this puzzle, please post an answer